# Deleting Realm database while parsing objects

Tags: ios, realm

I'm working on an app that uses Realm as database. User can log out at any time and this deletes all objects in realm.

But as my app uses networking, I may be in process of parsing objects at the same time, and I get crash.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'
```

Here is my logout function:

```
- (void)logout {
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [realm deleteAllObjects];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];

    [self showLoginScreen];
}
```

What is the correct way to handle this? I want to remove all data I have stored on logout.

Comment: I haven't used Realm, but just thinking off the top of my head, you could delete all the objects in a background thread, and put `@synchronized` blocks around the parsing code and the object deletion code (synchronizing on the same mutex, of course).  Alternatively, you might be able to copy the objects you get from Realm so you're not parsing the "live" copies, although I have no idea if Realm supports this.  Finally, you could try just checking whether each object is deleted, although that sounds kinda hackish.

Answer (score 0):

You can check via the property `invalidated` whether an object still exists. As locking mechanism you can use the write transaction itself, as these are exclusive with Realm. You enter only one write transaction at a single point in time.